# Proper way to define inputshape on the first layer on keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I have an array of 35000 images of 256x256 grayscale images

```
print(len(data))
>>>35000
print(data[0].shape)
>>>(256, 256)
```

My first layer is

```
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=(35000,), activation='relu'))
```

and it gives me the error

```
>>>ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_1: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2
```

what I'm doing wrong? what is the proper way to define the input shape?

Comment: Did you look at the [docs](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv2d)?

Comment: I tried with (256,256) too but got
`ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_1: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3`

Comment: right your missing RGB colors, unless you dont have that information, then maybe your should be using Conv1D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convolutional layers input shape: `(images, height, width, channels)`

So:

- input_shape=(256,256,1)
- batch_shape=(batch_size,256,256,1)
- batch_input_shape=(batch_size,256,256,1)

Comment: thanks, input_shape=(256,256,1) worked, I needed to give the number of channels