# proper way to define input data for keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to train a CNN on Keras

my data is made of 256x256 grayscale images

```
print(data.shape)
>>>(256, 256, 1000)
print(datay.shape)
>>>(256, 256, 1000)
```

and my model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=(256, 256, 1), activation='relu'))
...
# Various other layers
...
added.fit(data, datay, epochs=epochs, batch_size=32)
```

but when trying to train I get the following error

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (256, 256, 1000)
```

What am I doing wrong? What should be the proper way to define and shape my data prior to Keras? or is it that I'm not defining the Keras model the right way?

Comment: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py

Comment: ok so, my input shape being 
`(256,256,1)`
my data shape must be
`(1000,256,256,1)` thanks

Comment: As I recall, sometimes the channels come first but if it works for you... work off of examples, they're priceless in DL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper way to define inputshape on the first layer on keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47911093/proper-way-to-define-inputshape-on-the-first-layer-on-keras)